# Badminton and Cricket

Tags: cricket, technique, badminton

I've been playing badminton for quite some time now and   was wondering if my badminton skills help me in the cricket game?

Should I be more fit to be a batsman (hand-eye coordination), defending the wicket, or should I focus on being a bowler (smash, clears).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the techniques of badminton are unlikely to be directly transferable to cricket, nevertheless virtually any sport that improves hand-eye coordination will have a positive impact on one's cricket, particularly one's batting and fielding. The great English batsman Colin Cowdrey reputedly used to warm up for batting by playing the game of *rackets*. The young Don Bradman hit a golf ball against a wall with a stick. All such exercise is beneficial.

If anything, I would expect a player of racket sports to be more immediately comfortable with square-bat shots (the cut and the pull), and to require more training in straight-bat shots (particularly the drives).

If you are a beginner, I would advise against solely focussing your efforts on one discipline. By all means start with batting, since you have experience in a racket sport; however, you may also find you have ability as a bowler. The more "strings to your bow", the better!

Answer (score 0):

[Phil Horne](http://www.espncricinfo.com/newzealand/content/player/37251.html) of New Zealand was a double international player - representing his country at the highest levels of both cricket and badminton. So yes, there is evidence that the skills are transferable.

Comment: One data point proves very little.

Comment: yeah, it's just a footnote to the accepted answer